# Deriving the moment generating function of the negative binomial distribution?

Tags: statistics, summation, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

I am trying to follow a derivation of the moment generating function of the negative binomial distribution with parameters $k$ and $n$, but have found myself unable understand the following equivalence:

[image: derivation]

Clearly this implies that
$$
\sum_{x=k}^\infty {{x-1}\choose{k-1}} (qe^t)^{x-k} = (1-qe^t)^{-k}
$$
but I am unsure as to why this is the case

Comment: Looks like an application of the binomial theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing $x$ by $k+n$ gives
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+n-1}{k-1} (qe^t)^n , $$
which looks quite binomial already. You then want to move the dependence on $k$ to the lower argument of the binomial coefficient, which can be done as follows:
$$ \begin{align} 
\binom{k+n-1}{k-1} &= \frac{(k+n-1)!}{n!(k-1)!} \\
&= \frac{(k+n-1)(k+n-2) \dotsm (k+1)k }{n!} \\
&= (-1)^n \frac{(-k)(-k-1) \dotsm (k-n+1) }{n!} \\
&= (-1)^n \binom{-k}{n} ,
\end{align} $$
and it should be smooth sailing from here.